# how to increase width of svg path in css or inline

Tags: javascript, css, dictionary, svg, timezone

i have map svg of time zone but the size of time zone location is very small I want to increase the size of every time zone location

width minimum 400px;
height minimum 300px;

here is  a SVG code its some part of code

```
<svg width="960" height="960" fill="">
            <g class="timezones">
                <path d="M687.5779604596046,378.60433646441675L686.3875492168255,378.72410737996955L684.2083286352864,377.5908902558926L683.1139182991831,377.5079719297406L682.4803123151232,374.97435640843037L681.0978992589926,373.8779918737543L678.861078133448,373.54631856914637L679.6770858401918,372.8737588125804L680.3106918242516,372.5881512447236L679.5234843895106,370.01768313401243L679.6482855681891,368.6080715894289L677.6610668000013,368.0368564537153L677.1330618132848,368.4790875265258L676.1730527465274,366.06524292076836L676.4226551038844,365.29133854335L677.4114644426445,363.1446752107489L678.2370722400558,363.1446752107489L679.5330844801781,361.6060796032623L680.6082946349463,361.88247402376885L681.5875038830388,361.1362090884011L681.8659065123985,362.47211545418287L684.0547271846052,361.8179819923173L684.9667357980246,359.85558160672065L688.5091692543592,359.6528923650158L689.0275741504082,358.50124894623843L693.9908210255436,355.5714680888687L694.0196212975463,353.3787390195165L695.4692349883499,352.10732468518626L694.2500234735681,347.2888486210216L694.6244270096034,346.33989444394905L693.0116117774511,345.67654783473324L697.8404573832405,343.95368928024226L698.5412640019733,344.7460199523611L700.2020796874635,344.5433307106563L700.2212798687987,344.50647812125544L700.6340837675044,345.9437291078896L698.0900597405974,346.9018964323124L697.898057927246,347.73107969383216L700.5380828608286,348.7721653444069L703.6389121464548,349.24203585926807L706.1253356293563,350.4305318674464L706.4325385307187,351.13994421341323L702.352499997,350.27390836249265L700.0292780554472,350.5871553724001L700.2308799594663,351.591388433574L702.2660991809919,352.3192270742413L700.4612821354881,353.10234459900994L701.430891292913,354.8252031535009L701.2772898422318,356.61255373944346L700.2980805941393,357.37724496951165L700.1828795061284,358.7223644826437L698.0420592872596,360.67555172089016L698.6852653619869,361.84562143436796L698.6756652713194,365.23605965924867L700.0196779647797,365.2729122486495L700.0292780554472,369.73207556615563L699.6644746100794,373.86877872640406L700.3172807754745,374.6426831038225L700.6148835861692,378.1713185389564L699.7700756074228,377.94098985520094L698.6852653619869,379.498011757388L699.8564764234309,380.30876872420725L698.7140656339897,382.8515973928678L700.8356856715234,385.2101631145239L701.834095100951,387.6240077202813L701.7476942849429,389.87201567373484L700.2980805941393,390.3050335991951L700.6724841301747,391.3553323971201L701.9300960076267,391.65015311232713L701.4884918369183,394.5154419382453L700.2500801408014,393.2163881618644L698.7716661779951,395.02216504250737L698.75246599666,395.02216504250737L697.0820502205022,394.7918363587519L696.1508414257477,395.44596982061745L693.8852200282003,394.2666869597894L693.0116117774511,393.0689778042609L690.6691896545632,392.62674673145034L690.0643839425061,392.00946585898566L689.9875832171655,390.13919694689116L689.0947747850812,388.09387823514254L690.045183761171,387.72535234113377L690.5827888385551,388.76643799170853L691.3603961826285,388.1952228559949L691.1491941879419,386.0669858180943L690.179585030517,385.1272447883719L689.9491828544952,383.1832706974757L690.6211892012253,382.4185794674075L688.6147702517026,381.1748045751279Z">
                    <title>Asia/Kashgar</title>
                </path>
                <path d="M573.6440844168442,386.389445975352L574.9880971103045,385.91957546049076L575.0264974729747,387.6884997517329L575.0360975636423,387.6884997517329L574.8152954782881,388.619027634105L573.4808828754955,388.5268961606028L573.4040821501549,388.9875535281138L573.2312805181385,389.3100136853715L573.3368815154819,389.78909734758287L573.941687227539,390.6090674617524L573.1256795207952,391.9081212381333L574.6040934836016,391.43825072327206L573.2312805181385,397.46364909031547L573.0776790674573,397.6294857426194L571.3784630192969,392.2858602794922L571.9640685500189,391.1250037133646Z">
                    <title>Asia/Jerusalem</title>
                </path>
                <path d="M189.19885354320203,391.94497382753417L188.53644728713948,391.93576068018393L183.82280276936095,391.95418697488435L173.8291083844171,388.28735432949713L173.85790865641982,388.241288592746L174.08831083244158,387.58715513088043L174.07871074177402,387.58715513088043L174.6547161818284,386.61977465910746L174.06911065110643,385.3944260615283L174.57791545648783,383.70842009643815L175.65312561125603,382.63969500381273L174.30911291779577,380.6404420288152L174.4819145498121,379.6638484096919L173.9827098350983,376.69721496292135L175.87392769661022,376.3379022162628L175.86432760594266,373.656876337349L183.07399569729023,373.6476631899988L181.76838336650027,375.2876034183378L182.16198708387077,377.8120057922979L183.1603965132984,377.775153202897L183.371598507985,379.7467667358439L189.2084536338696,379.70991414644305ZM184.41800839075051,375.7759002278994L184.47560893475594,375.69298190174743L185.84842190021894,375.5824241335448L185.36841736684028,376.7432806996724L185.81002153754864,376.9736093834279L186.46282770294363,377.2592169512847L186.00202335090012,378.5582707276656L183.99560440137728,378.4569261068132L183.99560440137728,376.052294648406Z">
                    <title>America/Phoenix</title>
                </path>
                <path d="M496.9969605269386,327.8122551226582L497.16976215895494,326.9830718611385L496.36335454287877,325.02988462289204L496.3825547242139,324.93775314938983L497.0641611616116,324.145422477271L496.06575173218397,322.42256392278L496.6033568095681,319.8428826647186L495.8737499188325,317.90812172117256L497.09296143361433,317.843629689721L498.87857829778295,315.4758508207147L497.87056877768777,314.96912771645265L498.8209777537775,314.29656795988666L499.2337816524832,311.66160781772396L499.2721820151535,309.75448631622857L501.4322024153575,309.56101022187397L502.0178079460795,310.9245560297064L502.94901674083405,308.78710584445554L503.9762264422644,308.74104010770446L502.89141619682863,306.87077119560996L503.9378260795941,305.81125925033473L503.0738179195125,304.0607612537931L505.2626385917192,304.3555819690001L506.4242495624956,304.5490580633547L507.0290552745527,306.01394849203956L509.6018795734624,307.33142856312094L508.68027086937536,308.05926720378824L510.533088368217,308.64890863420226L511.1762944429444,307.54333095217595L512.289904960383,307.52490465747553L514.7475281712817,306.2350640284448L515.7459376007093,307.4696257733742L516.5331450354504,307.460412626024L516.8595481181478,308.8147452865062L518.0403592702594,309.60707595862505L518.4435630782974,311.47734487071955L517.665955734224,313.4121058142656L519.038768699687,314.5729623803932L519.3555716917169,316.80254403914626L518.8947673396734,317.8620559844215L520.1043787637876,320.34960576898067L519.5283733237333,321.9066276711677L518.3763624436244,321.76843046091443L516.158741499415,322.58840057508394L514.5075259045924,323.8782412041146L513.3555150244836,323.9519463829164L512.5779076804101,325.14044239109467L513.0675123044564,326.55926708302843L516.9171486621533,330.60383876977465L516.5715453981206,331.6449244203494L513.9891210085434,333.2848646486884L514.6995277179439,334.30752400456277L514.065921733884,335.03536264523007L510.94589226692267,335.35782280248776L510.04348374417077,336.06723514845464L507.86426316263163,335.45916742334015L507.1442563625636,336.5739582527167L506.6066512851795,335.5052331600913L505.45464040507073,335.5236594547917L502.96821692216923,334.48257380421694L501.36500178068445,335.4775937180406L500.2129909005757,335.35782280248776L500.0305891778918,334.8971654349768L500.79859643129765,331.36852999984285L501.9314071300713,329.7746555082549L499.867387636543,328.94547224673516L497.94736950302837,329.0007511308365ZM515.2755331579982,306.01394849203956L516.3411432220989,305.5440779771784L516.7155467581342,306.67729510125537L515.3811341553416,307.082673584665Z">
                    <title>Europe/Berlin</title>
                </path>
                <path d="M533.3333037037037,548.1631002978511L533.3333037037037,540.1660883978608L536.0021289092891,540.175301545211L535.9925288186215,529.6999530080118L537.2405406054061,529.6999530080118L542.1173866645333,528.8062777150406L542.9813948246149,530.2158892596241L544.5270094220942,528.8523434517916L547.3494360783608,528.2166362846265L547.3782363503635,528.2442757266772L548.760649406494,530.593628300983L549.7590588359217,533.1364569696436L552.6582862175288,534.8593155241346L552.7638872148722,535.8727617326587L553.8102970976377,535.8451222906081L553.8582975509755,537.5771939924492L554.7319058017247,538.9499529476318L557.5351322766561,539.6501521462485L558.2935394393944,540.7280903862242L555.5863138711387,541.8244549209003L552.0054800521339,544.9477118726245L551.6406766067661,546.7166361638667L550.4022649106491,547.822213845893L548.9622513105131,548.199952887252L548.2134442384424,550.7519947032627L547.5894383450501,551.1573731866724L544.9974138648054,551.1481600393222L542.5685909259092,549.7016959053377L540.9461756030894,550.3097636304522L540.5813721577216,551.9128512693903L537.7685455921226,554.4280404960002L535.013319570529,554.1977118122447L535.6373254639213,552.2260982792977L534.360513405134,548.9922835593709Z">
                    <title>Africa/Gaborone</title>
                </path>
                <path d="M820.6736174748414,380.3916870503592L820.5776165681657,380.4285396397601L819.4832062320623,382.05926672074895L818.0047922692561,381.8842169210948L817.399986557199,382.5752029723612L817.5727881892153,380.6404420288152L816.8239811171445,380.48381852386143L817.217584834515,378.18053168630667L817.8895911812452,377.0104619728288L816.9583823864906,373.6476631899988L818.0719929039291,373.73979466350096L817.3807863758637,371.10483452133826L817.803190365237,370.9021452796335L819.0224018800188,369.2622050512945L821.518425453588,369.2622050512945L822.2960327976614,368.22111940071966L822.958439053724,369.8149938923076L825.1184594539279,373.43576080094374L824.9936582752495,376.1536392692584L825.5600636246363,376.92754364667684L825.1664599072658,378.6964679379189L823.8896478484785,380.1060794825025L822.9008385097185,379.7375535884937L822.4496342483425,380.677294618216Z">
                    <title>Asia/Seoul</title>
                </path>
                <path d="M587.7082172448391,508.20568023995037L584.5881877778778,510.0114571205933L582.6105691003577,510.64716428775847L581.6409599429328,510.2233595096484L579.8745432600992,511.51320013867905L578.1561270306037,511.1078216552694L576.4857112544458,511.45792125457774L573.2216804274709,511.07096906586855L572.2712714513812,509.5968654898335L572.0120690033567,506.75921610596595L570.7640572165722,505.4325228875344L570.5048547685477,506.0221643179484L567.8744299256326,505.1837679090785L565.1672043573769,504.1518954058539L563.8711921172545,503.1200229026294L562.7287813278133,503.0002519870765L562.0663750717507,502.00523207325284L560.4919602022687,498.55030181692064L558.9175453327866,496.7076723468768L558.370340164735,491.8615568406615L560.1367568475684,491.3548337363994L561.2983678183449,489.3740070561023L562.2199765224319,488.68302100483584L561.0871658236582,487.62350905956066L561.5095698130315,486.4534393460828L562.2679769757698,486.19547122027666L562.2199765224319,484.41733378168436L561.2695675463422,482.83267243744666L562.0183746184128,482.64840949044225L570.4568543152099,482.64840949044225L570.9464589392561,482.7313278165943L580.4697488814888,488.15787160587337L580.2777470681374,489.38322020345254L584.5881877778778,492.4880508604764L583.4073766257662,496.1456703585134L583.8105804338044,497.25124804053974L585.4905963006297,499.04781177383245L584.7321891378914,500.3100129608125L584.7129889565563,502.27241334640917L585.6345976606433,504.280879468757L586.1434024660247,506.4459690960585Z">
                    <title>Africa/Dar_es_Salaam</title>
                </path>
                <path d="M288.6461927685943,426.39293177000377L288.9629957606242,428.01444570364237L288.3581900485671,428.4290373344022L288.6461927685943,431.110063213316L287.84938524318574,430.5296349302522L285.8333662029953,430.80602935075876L284.29735169618357,430.4190771620496L282.9917393653936,431.12848950801646L281.3981243145764,429.96763294188884L282.05093047997144,429.2766468906224L286.08296856035224,429.98605923658926L287.16777880578803,429.3227126273735L285.82376611232775,428.1987086506467L285.96776747234134,427.10234411597065L284.2109508801754,426.1165373494972L285.9197670190035,425.6927325713871Z">
                    <title>America/Port-au-Prince</title>
                </path>
                <path d="M307.9999755544222,326.06175712611656L308.93118434917676,325.8222152950109L312.7904207975413,327.00149815583893L315.5456468191348,329.15737463579023L314.0000322216555,329.44298220364703L311.7344108241082,328.7612092997308ZM280.5437162451624,345.3080219407245L281.8013281226145,344.61703588945807L281.64772667193336,343.1982111975243L280.1117121651216,342.90339048231726L277.82689058623913,343.9168366908414L275.580469370027,343.18899805017406L272.7964430764307,340.7383008550158L270.1276178708453,340.3144960769057L268.1787994653279,337.31101004073423L267.95799737997373,335.49602001274104L267.9387971986386,319.3914384445579L269.5900127934612,319.70468545446533L269.21560925742585,318.10159781552716L270.44442086287523,316.6735599762432L270.57882213222126,314.98755401115307L269.4460114334476,312.77639864710045L269.45561152411517,311.1640978608121L269.13880853208525,307.4972652154249L268.11159883065494,306.7325739853567L267.59319393460595,305.1294863464185L271.22202820694866,303.3882014972271L274.33245758324244,300.5505521133596L275.9068724527245,297.13247444642826L275.77247118337846,293.4103629169397L275.062064473978,290.80304221682763L273.20924697513635,287.8916876541584L270.4252206815401,285.8463689424097L271.55803138031376,282.99029326384175L272.78684298576314,282.0044864973683L272.2108375457087,281.5806817192582L272.9980449804498,280.3645462690293L273.79485250585833,279.89467575416813L273.1132460684606,278.5679825357365L272.86364371110375,274.55105029104095L271.394829838965,274.5694765857414L272.74844262309284,272.1924845693849L271.5388311989786,267.67804236777744L271.5388311989786,266.0657415814891L273.2764476098094,264.42580135315006L274.8220622072887,264.67455633160597L278.47969675163415,266.2592176758437L279.180503370367,265.9643969606367L280.99492050653834,267.09761408471365L281.35012386123856,266.3789885913965L283.57734489611556,265.06150852031516L286.4189717337173,268.07420770383686L289.27019866198657,270.15637900498643L288.4637910459104,270.38670768874186L288.6845931312646,271.7502534965743L291.75662214488807,273.2796359567107L292.98543375033745,272.8742574733011L293.1486352916862,274.26544272318415L295.0014527905279,273.795572208323L294.14704472111384,275.0946259847039L293.9454428170948,277.1123052544019L294.3390465344653,278.3560801466815L293.12943511035104,279.00100046119684L294.53104834781675,279.48008412340823L294.3390465344653,282.52042274898054L295.3374559638929,282.3085203599255L295.75025986259857,283.7273450518593L294.24304562778957,285.1185303017424L292.78383184631844,285.0356119755904L293.8398418197515,286.1872553943678L295.32785587322536,284.5288888713284L297.09427255605885,284.57495460807945L297.88147999079985,286.48207610957485L298.89908960156265,286.58342073042724L299.7726978523118,288.01145856971124L302.1631204285376,286.7031916459801L302.7967264125974,284.91584106003756L303.71833511668444,285.2106617752446L304.9855470848041,283.81026337801126L304.6687440927742,282.6309805171832L305.2159492608259,280.3276936796284L306.31995968759685,279.39716579725626L307.06876675966754,277.6282415060142L306.84796467431335,278.4574247675339L308.0575760984276,284.09587094586806L308.9599846211795,285.3488589854979L310.140795773291,284.639446639531L310.73600139468056,285.28436695404633L309.219187069204,285.62525340600445L309.7855924185908,286.740044235381L308.15357700510333,288.73929721037854L309.9679941412747,291.2084207002373L309.6415910585772,294.69099039862016L308.9599846211795,295.6030919862919L309.2479873412067,298.173560097003L310.2175964986316,298.80005411681793L310.140795773291,301.63770350068546L311.07200456804566,301.7114086794872L309.5647903332366,304.687255273608L309.5839905145718,305.46115965102643L306.46396104761044,303.7843668332865L304.7935452714527,304.9728628414648L301.8175171645049,301.9601636579431L302.3839225138918,304.52141862130406L301.3951131751317,304.4385002951521L300.579105468388,306.05080108144045L299.26389304693043,306.29955605989636L299.1678921402547,308.16982497199086L300.52150492438255,310.27042256784085L301.58711498848317,310.94298232440684L301.2607119057857,312.3986596057415L300.40630383637165,313.1449245411092L301.5775148978156,314.0385998340805L303.03672867928674,312.67505402624806L303.0847291326246,315.5219165574658L303.7471353886872,316.6367073868423L305.3695507115071,316.64592053419256L306.16635823691564,318.08317152082674L308.5375806318063,318.23979502578044L308.93118434917676,313.91882891852765L310.4383985839858,313.38446637221494L310.9664035707023,314.1952233390342L309.08478579985797,315.0981117793557L309.8815933252665,315.8075241253226L309.8239927812611,317.12500419640395L327.70896169495023,317.14343049110437L327.7281618762854,318.36877908868354L327.737761966953,318.84786275089493L326.18254727880606,318.8755021929456L326.1441469161358,318.8755021929456L323.5617225265585,319.81524322266796L323.5425223452234,319.81524322266796L321.5169032143654,322.78187666943853L321.08489913432464,322.7542372273879L321.0560988623219,323.27017347900016L321.04649877165434,323.2978129210508L319.3088823608236,324.062504151119L316.6304570645706,324.062504151119L315.74724872315386,324.817982233837L309.5647903332366,324.3481117189758L302.78712632192986,324.4863089292291L300.915108641753,326.54084078832796L300.3583033830338,328.39268340572204L298.3326842521758,328.58615950007663L295.8270605879392,330.60383876977465L294.1374446304463,333.14666743843514L293.5710392810594,334.6484104565209L290.2302077287439,338.32445624925833L292.0254246835801,337.59661760859103L295.8270605879392,332.76892839707614L298.19828298282977,331.13820131608736L302.26872142588087,329.24950610929244L305.11994835415015,328.6690778262286L306.7903641303079,328.8625539205832L308.76798280782805,330.2905917598672L308.4607799064657,332.0503029037591L306.1855584182508,333.57968536389546L304.1311390153901,332.9439781967303L302.1823206098727,333.6533905426972L301.91351807118065,333.7455220161994L300.3583033830338,334.34437659396366L299.72469739897394,333.7086694267985L297.6510778147781,334.05876902610686L297.6510778147781,335.4868068653908L295.8462607692743,336.4910399265647L295.39505650789835,335.8553327593996L293.3406371050377,338.8864582376217L292.5342294889615,340.7935797391171L292.70703112097783,341.77938650559054L291.0462154354876,344.4604123845043L289.8846044647113,344.20244425869816L289.23179829931627,345.33566138277513Z">
                    <title>America/Montreal</title>
                </path>

            </g>
         </svg>
```

here is the current size of every time zone location it is very little size

[image: size of svg time zone location]

how to increase size of every path by id or class

```
<g>
<path class='gmt' id=''d="M687.5.........> 
<path class='ist' id=''d="M687.5.........> 
<path class='pkt' id=''d="M687.5.........> 
<path class='est' id=''d="M687.5.........> 
</g>
```

every location of time zone look clear on screen

Comment: increase the stroke-width I imagine.

Comment: i add this line of code  path {  
   stroke-width:220px;
   }    but no effect on size

Comment: added where? Please create a [mcve] in the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_stroking.asp) you can find an example of what you're trying to achieve.

They use the stroke-width property:

> **SVG stroke-width Property:** The stroke-width property defines the
> thickness of a line, text or outline of an element

```
<path stroke-width="2" d="........" />
```