# Can mui icons have their stroke width changed?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I would like to customise the icons that come with @mui/material. Specifically, the [empty checkbox](https://mui.com/material-ui/material-icons/?query=check&selected=CheckBoxOutlineBlank) icon (as well as empty radio). I would like to make the stroke thinner. I have tried setting stroke-width, font weight, font size (this just makes it smaller, not thinner). Is this possible?

I would like to avoid resorting to editing the underlying path if i can help it.

Answer (score 1):

you cant change [empty checkbox](https://mui.com/material-ui/material-icons/?query=check&selected=CheckBoxOutlineBlank)  width because icon widths depend on path property not stroke value.
you can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46021894/how-to-increase-width-of-svg-path-in-css-or-inline)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try changing the stroke color to match the background color (for example, white). This worked for my purposes!

Comment: 'try' should be a comment not an answer

Answer (score 1):

Yes figured this out after quite a lot of searching and testing. Hope this helps

Here are 2 ways to do it that I've been using:

#### 1. With Material UI's sx styling method

```js
import ArrowBackIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ArrowBack';

<ArrowBackIcon
     sx={{ 
          stroke: "blue",
          strokeWidth: 2
     }}
/>
```

#### 2. With a styled-components method

I personally prefer this method to keep out a bunch of inline styles from my code...and helps to allow all of the style wrapping into the component or its related parts.

```js
import ArrowBackIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ArrowBack';
import styled from "styled-components";

export const StyledArrowBack = styled(ArrowBackIcon)`
    stroke: blue;
    stroke-width: 2;
`;
```